# Creating CSS3 round corners in Opera

Tags: opera, css

i understand how to create CSS3 round corners in FF & webkit however how would one create them in opera purely with CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just use**

```
border-radius: 5px; 

/* or if you need to specify individual corners */
border-radius: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
```

Comment: IE9 supports this as well. Man I hate the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` vendor extensions.

Comment: Tell me about it @BoltClock! - they annoy me as well especially because only `some` properties need the prefix. Eventually, the vendor-specific prefixes will dissapear and they'll just follow the spec. And there will be 1000's of stylesheets with redundant attributes. Booo

Comment: eventually the spec will be agreed, then all the browsers will be able to follow it, in the meantime the vendor extensions are for your own good.

Comment: @BoltClock `border-radius` is an especially good example of where vendor prefixes are needed. Firefox and WebKit initially tried different syntaxes for `border-radius`. At least with the prefixes, if the older versions of the browsers hang around, your `border-radius` code won’t break on them.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers, Turns out that Webkit(Chrome) beta now uses

```
border-radius:5px;
```

as well no need to use

```
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
```

neat. Mozilla will soon support this is guess.

Comment: If a product is in beta, how does that constitute "no need to use". Current (and older) Chrome browsers will `FAIL`, leaving you with an ugly UI.

Comment: But yeah, dosen't solve firefox. this is my biggest fear of css3! having huge code chunks for new techniques. webkit,mozilla etc.

Comment: @etoxin Chrome might auto-update but Safari doesn't, and neither do many of the other WebKit based browsers

Comment: @robertc very true. makes me wonder why they came out with -moz- & -webkit- least opera was smart!

Comment: @etoxin because the standard isn't yet finalised so any current implementation is, by definition, non-standard.  It's only really become an issue because CSS rounded corners i such a popular feature, even while still in 'beta'.  There are quite a number of edge cases where the different browsers have markedly different results, try setting one or two border-widths to zero an an element with border-radius applied and compare the results in a few different browsers.  Here's some examples: http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/css3/borders.html

Comment: @etoxin: Opera has the `-o-`prefix for its own experimental properties.